# Return a string from a web scraping function in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Ok so I am scraping some basic data of a web page. I wanted to refactor out my code to another class and return a string from what I retrieved but it is difficult with the asynchronous function and I'm new with swift.

I now realize that this function is incapable of returning a string but I can't quite figure out how to configure the completion handler and how to call the function after from the main class using the completion handler.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
func getNameFromProfileUrl(profileUrl: NSURL) -> String {

        var playerName = ""

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl,     completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

                var urlContentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<title>")


                var statusArray = urlContentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")

                playerName = statusArray[0] as! String

            }

        })
        task.resume()
        return playerName
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you'll want to provide a completion handler to this function from the main class that can handle *just* the return of the player name (or not). You'd change the function to not have a return value, but to accept a second parameter that is a completion handler:

```
func getNameFromProfileUrl(profileUrl: NSURL, completionHandler: (String?) -> Void) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!
            var urlContentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<title>")
            var statusArray = urlContentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
            let playerName = statusArray[0] as? String

            completionHandler(playerName)
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

From your main class, you'd then call it with something like this:

```
myWebScraper.getNameFromProfileUrl(profileURL) { playerName in
    // always update UI from the main thread
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        if let playerName = playerName {
            playerNameField.text = playerName
        } else {
            playerNameField.text = "Player Not Found"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i'll give it a shot this evening, looks like exactly what i envisioned!